# Can I save King Foltest?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I had grown quite attached to King Foltest in our brief time spent together. Sure, he had his weak points, as a man and especially as a father, but he seemed to be honorable enough and was grateful when I saved his life.

### THEN HE DIED.

Well, that sucks. I just feel like a lousy king protector at the moment. Is there any decision path, perhaps using imported data from The Witcher 1, that will let me save his life?

Comment: The guy was an **se (by design). It's only the on-rails nature of the game that stopped me from slitting his throat inside 2 minutes. When I track down the actual assassin, I'll buy him a beer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game is called The Witcher 2: **Assassins of Kings**.

If Foltest doesn't die, then there's really no plot for the game to follow.

There is no way to save him.

Comment: Oh man. I thought *I* was going to be the assassin. s. :*(

Comment: +1 for "It's the title!"  "I'm playing Lufia - why do I have to go to the Fortress of Doom?"

Comment: Hey man, you never know.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you will have to suck it up, because that's the main story line in the game.

According to the game guide, there is no known affect to this. The King will die whatever you do or do not.